# Cannot install mod_v8 in FreeSwitch

Tags: javascript, v8, voip, freeswitch

I get below error when I try to install mod_v8 with 'load mod_v8' command. As documentation says I checked to modules.conf for uncomment 'languages/mod_v8' line but that file is empty.Also I uncommented mod_v8 line in 'modules.conf.xml' file but module still not loads.

```
switch_loadable_module.c:1750 Error Loading module /usr/lib/freeswitch/mod/mod_v8.so
**/usr/lib/freeswitch/mod/mod_v8.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
```

Any Help ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try to install mod_v8 with 'load mod_v8' command

Per the [documentation](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_v8), installing and loading are two separate steps and you need to do both:

1. *Install* mod_v8 by executing `make mod_v8-install`
2. *Load* mod_v8 by executing `load mod_v8`.

The second won't work without the first. The error message "no such file or directory" suggests that this might be the problem.

That said, the same documentation also says that mod_v8 should be available by default since 2014. So, if you need further help, please give more information:

- which version of FreeSwitch are you using?
- what exactly have you done so far? (Which commands in which order?)
- which documentation specifically have you followed?

Comment: Thank for the reply.
I have FreeSwitch version 1.10.7 installed from Debian packages.

Comment: Thank for the reply.
I have FreeSwitch version 1.10.7 installed from Debian packages.
I follow freeswitch.org documentation for configuration. Unfortunately mod_v8 is not installed by default. When I try to use javascript application inside dialplan error log occurs and says that "Invalid Application javascript". I can't install javascript module because there is no any modules.conf file in the server that FreeSwitch installed.

Comment: I want to correct my reply. Actually there is one modules.conf file but it's empty.

Comment: @Hüseyn Maybe the Debian packages aren't set up to support mod_v8. You could try compiling from source. Looks like the `bootstrap.sh` script will create `modules.conf` from https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch/blob/master/build/modules.conf.in, which has mod_v8 commented out by default.

Comment: I did so and it's working now. I installed freeswitch from source and followed instructions from freeswitch.org documantation in order to enable mod_v8. It's okay now. Thank you)